# Cisco Catalyst 2960: incorrect data in the Web interface

Tags: cisco, cisco-2960

Found this problem in the web interface on Cisco WS-C2960G-24TC-L: the "Smartports" descriptions of the ports do not corresponds to the actual configuration received from memory with the command `show running-config`.

For example, in CLI a port appears as a trunk port, but in the web interface it can be seen as `vlan 1`. I noticed this on two switches. Firmware: `12.2(55)SE9`

To what could the problem be related?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Without a screenshot we can only make an assumption.

One thing I will point out is that vlan 1 is the native vlan by default on a trunk port. The native vlan is used to send untagged traffic via a trunk.

Perhaps this is what the CLI is displaying.